# JQuery Dialog Close issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build Jquery Dialog to show multiple pop ups on the screen, but sometimes the OK button is not performing any actions.

```
function alert_popup_msg(_msg)
{
   var id = "" + (new Date()).getTime();
   var popDiv = "<div id='" + id + "' class=\"dialog-size def-popup\"><div  class=\"popup-background\"><label class=\"color-white no-text-shadow center-align font-helv-16-bold std-padding-a\">Alert</label><label class=\"color-white no-text-shadow center-align font-helv-12-reg std-padding-a\">"+_msg+"</label><div class=\"center-align\"><a class=\"btn-simple-black-orange btn-text btn-login\" id=\"okButtonCallBack\">Ok</a></div></div></div> ";                                             
   $.mobile.activePage.append(popDiv).trigger("pagecreate");

   $( "#" + id ).dialog({
      modal: false,

    });
   $("#okButtonCallBack").click(function(event){
            $("#" + id).dialog("close");
            $("#" + id).remove();
   });

};
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue? It is blocking the user to do any action. Even if you navigate back and come back to the same screen, the popup still shows unless you refresh the whole screen.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: You can't use the same `id="okButtonCallBack"` in all the dialogs, since IDs have to be unique.

Comment: Are you using JQuery Mobile and JQuery UI together? They have some conflicts with each other, including conflicts with dialogs. Are you trying to use the JQuery UI dialog or the JQuery Mobile dialog? Your reference to $.mobile indicates you are using jquery mobile, but the dialog syntax is for the JQuery UI dialog. If you are using JQuery Mobile, it's recommended to use the JQuery Mobile popup widget. Docs: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/

Answer (score 0):

Your ok button shouldn't have an id but should be specified via a CSS class, as IDs are unique by definition and your code currently breaks with multiple dialogs imho (as `$("#example")` will always return the first result).

Answer (score 0):

Change `id="okButtonCallBack"` to `class="okButtonCallBack"`, since IDs have to be unique. Then write the handler:

```
$(document).on("click", ".okButtonCallBack", function() {
    var dialog = $(this).closest(".def-popup");
    dialog.dialog("close").remove();
}
```

This handler can be specified just once, it doesn't need to be bound in the `alert_popup_msg` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` instead of `click`, and may i suggest, don't use IDs in the IDs attibutes, you don't need more than 1 dialog at the time.

This will "listen" to node changes in the `body` that matches with the class `dialog-ok-button` and bind the callback to the `click` event when it is inserted into the DOM. So no need to re-run this code more than once.

```
$('body').on('click', '.dialog-ok-button', function(event){
    $(".dialog").dialog("close");
    $(".dialog").remove();
});
```